# If $A = \{x_n:n\ge 1\}$ is totally bounded, then $(x_n)$ has a Cauchy subsequence (Carothers, Lemma 7.3)

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, proof-explanation

> Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence in $(M,d)$, and let $A = \{x_n:n\ge 1\}$ be the range of the sequence. If $A$ is totally bounded, then $(x_n)$ has a Cauchy subsequence.

First, here are the definitions/characterizations of totally bounded I know:

> $A\subset (M,d)$ is said to be totally bounded if for all $\epsilon>0$, there exist finitely many points $x_1,\ldots,x_n\in M$ such that $A\subset\bigcup_{i=1}^n B(x_i,\epsilon)$. Equivalently, $A\subset (M,d)$ is said to be totally bounded if for all $\epsilon>0$, there exist finitely many points $x_1,\ldots,x_n\in A$ such that $A\subset\bigcup_{i=1}^n B(x_i,\epsilon)$.

> $A$ is totally bounded iff for all $\epsilon>0$,  there are finitely many sets $A_1,A_2,...,A_n\subset A$ with $\text{diam}(A_i) < \epsilon$ for all $1\le i\le n$ such that $A\subset \bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i$. (The $A_i$'s might as well be subsets of $M$, we don't care - it is easy to see the equivalence of the two characterisations).

I need some help in **understanding the proof**:

1. If $A$ is finite, we are done. *Is the following reasoning correct*: If $A$ is finite, then $x_n$ is eventually constant. Eventually constant sequences are Cauchy themselves - and so have a Cauchy subsequence. $\color{red}{\text{(Resolved).}}$
2. Why is $A_1$ also totally bounded? We know that $A\subset \cup_{i=1}^n A_i$, where $A_1$ contains infinitely many points of $A$. I know that subsets of a totally bounded set are also totally bounded, but $A_1\subset A$ is not necessarily true! $\color{red}{\text{(Resolved).}}$
3. Why does the author write **(How?)** in the second last line. Isn't it obvious that I can pick $x_{n_k}\in A_k$ since all the $A_k$'s are non-empty? What is there to justify? $\color{red}{\text{(Resolved).}}$
4. $\text{diam}(A_k) < 1/k$ by construction, but why is $\text{diam}\{x_{n_j}:j\ge k\} \le \text{diam}(A_k)$? We need this to conclude that the chosen subsequence is indeed Cauchy. $\color{red}{\text{(Resolved).}}$
5. I could simply have selected $1/2^k$ instead of $1/k$ right (or any other monotone decreasing function of $k$)? I don't find the choice of $1/k$ special. $\color{red}{\text{(Resolved).}}$

Here's the proof attached for reference:

> [image]

Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: **1)** Not so clear what you wrote.If $A$ is finite, there is $a\in A$ s.t. $|\{n\in\mathbb N\mid x_n=1\}|=\infty $. **2)** As written in your definition, $A_i\subset A$. **3)** Be careful. Take $a\in A_1$. There is $n$ s.t. $a=x_n$. Set $i_1=n$. Now, take $b\in A_2$. There is $m=:i_2$ s.t. $b=x_m$, but there is no reason for $m>n$.... continue like that.  The sequence $(x_{i_k})$ won't be a subsequence of $(x_n)$ because $(i_n)$ won't be strictly increasing a priori. **4)** As construct, $x_{n_k}\in A_p$ for all $k\geq p$. So, yes $\{x_{n_k}\mid k\geq p\}\subset A_p$. **5)** Yes.

Comment: Could you elaborate some more on $3?$ Still don't quite get the idea. Understood the rest!

Comment: Take for example $A_n=[0,\frac{1}{n}]\cap\{1/n\mid n\in\mathbb N\}$ and let say that $x_n=\frac{1}{n}$. You pick an element in $A_1$, let say $\frac{1}{4}$. This correspond for example to $x_4$. So, you set $n_1=4$. Now, you can not take any element in $A_2$, for example, you can't take $\frac{1}{2}$ or $\frac{1}{3}$ because this correspond to $x_2$ and $x_3$, and to have that $(x_{n_j})$ is a subsequence, you must take $n_2>4$. So, for example, you can take $n_2=10$, and $x_{n_2}=\frac{1}{10}\in A_2$.

Comment: Same for $A_3$, you cannot take any element of $A_3$, for example, you can't take $\{\frac{1}{3},\cdots,\frac{1}{10}\}$, because for all these numbers, the sequence will reach them at a rank that is smaller than $11$, and you need $n_3\geq 11$. etc...

Comment: Got it, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A_1 \subseteq A$ is true! $A$ is a **union** by finitely many sets of diameter $<1$ (we can take $\varepsilon=\frac12$ in the definition of being totally bounded and know there are $x_1, \ldots x_n$ so that $A \subseteq \bigcup_{i=1}^n B(x_i, \frac12)$, we just take $A_1  =B(x_i, \frac12) \cap A$ for the ball that contains infinitely many points of $A$. So $_1$ is still totally bounded and its diameter is at most the diameter of $B(x_i, \frac12)$ which is $\le 1$ by the triangle inequality..

The above process we can keep on doing, using recursion.

Picking $x_{n_k}$ as a *subsequence* needs that each $A_k$ has infinitely many elements, not just non-emptyness: for $x_{n_1}$ we use non-emptyness, but then we need some $x_n$ with $n > n_1$ to be in $A_2$ and this is what the infinity of points gives us. This keeps on: having $n_k$ we need elements with larger index than $n_k$ to be in $A_{k+1}$ to keep the subsequence going (which must have a *monotonically increasing* subset $n_1 < n_2 < \ldots$ as indices).

And yes any other decreasing sequence of diameters would have done just as well, as long as it goes below any given $\varepsilon>0$.

Comment: So, to choose $x_{n_k}\in A_k$ we are only using the non-emptiness and infinitude of $A_k$'s right? That $A_k$ is infinite for all $k$, follows directly from the construction. I hope I'm right!

Comment: @strawberry-sunshine yes. The fact that the sets are infinite (by construction) is the essential thing.